# Split address by delimer and create new column in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

I want to split address based on delimeter (,)
[image: extract number from address and split address using (,)]

the code i have written `select substring_index(Propertyaddress,',') from housingdata;`
however it shows an error saying `incorrect parameter call to native function`
i am using mysql workbench.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index , count is not optional..

Comment: why are the number, the street name and the city in the same field? Never heard about database normalization? You should fix your DB design before going further

Comment: @cid hello i am beginer in sql i got data in csv excel and uploaded csv in workbench, and by default  it took everything as text for some column such as `propertyaddress` i have converted to `varchar`. if there is any solution for db normalization or doc. please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substring_index` needs a third parameter.

Try this to get the part before and the part after the comma `,`:

```
select substring_index(Propertyaddress,',', 1),
select substring_index(Propertyaddress,',', -1) 
from housingdata;
```

`substring_index` returns a substring from a string before the specified number of occurrences of the delimiter. With `1` as the third parameter, it gets the part of the string before the first encountered comma. With `-1` it returns the substring from the right of the last comma.

Comment: `select substring_index(Propertyaddress,',', -1) 
from housingdata; `  this works thanks, can you please tell me why you have written 2 select statment and whats the importence of `-1`  and how to extract only number from address in this case `1808`

Comment: @alex check my edited answer.

Comment: @alex to get the number you can try substring_index(Propertyaddress,' ', 1). Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it worked for you ^^

Comment: Did it already ^^

Comment: @alex have a nice day ^__^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242332/discussion-between-alex-and-zakaria).